# Fastest way to upload a Datatable to SQLite

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite, sqlbulkcopy

So, I was using SQL Server but there is a need for me to change to SQLite.
I had the following code that worked very fast for 600.000 rows (about a minute).

```vb
Dim SQLAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dtKinoDraws As New DataTable
Dim SQLcmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder

'Emptying the Database
ExecuteSQLQuery(<SQL>
                    USE <%= DatabaseName %>
                    TRUNCATE TABLE [<%= DatabaseName %>].[dbo].<%= KinoDrawsTableName %>
                </SQL>.Value)

'This is so we have the SCHEMA to use dtKinoDraws.NewRow later to add the 400.000 rows
SQLAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(<SQL>
                                     USE <%= DatabaseName %>
                                     Select * FROM [<%= DatabaseName %>].[dbo].<%= KinoDrawsTableName %>
                                </SQL>.Value, SQLConn)
SQLcmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(SQLAdapter)
SQLAdapter.Fill(dtKinoDraws)

[Adding the 600.000+ rows to the datatable dtKinoDraws as described below]

'Copying everything from the datatable back to SQL Server (takes about a minute)
Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(SQLConn)
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = KinoDrawsTableName
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(item)
End Using

SQLAdapter.Update(dtKinoDraws)
SQLAdapter.Dispose()
SQLConn.Close()
```

Now I tried to do the same with SQLite but there is no SQLiteBulkCopy, modelling after my previous code and after searching stack overflow for a way, I wrote this extremely inefficient and snail-slow piece of code (takes literally HOURS):

```vb
Dim SQLiteAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim dtKinoDraws As New DataTable
Dim SQLitecmdBuilder As SQLiteCommandBuilder

'Emptying the Database
ExecuteSQLQuery(<SQL>
                    DELETE FROM [<%= KinoDrawsTableName %>];
                    VACUUM;
                </SQL>.Value)

'This is so we have the SCHEMA to use dtKinoDraws.NewRow later to add the 400.000 rows
SQLiteAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(<SQL>
                                          Select * FROM <%= KinoDrawsTableName %>
                                      </SQL>.Value, SQLConnLite)
SQLitecmdBuilder = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(SQLiteAdapter)

SQLiteAdapter.Fill(dtKinoDraws)

[Adding the 600.000+ rows to the datatable dtKinoDraws as described below]

SQLiteAdapter.Update(dtKinoDraws)
SQLiteAdapter.Dispose()
SQLConnLite.Close()
```

Visual Studio's Output gives me a nearly infinite number of this message at least twice a second: "SQLite notice (27): delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict at line 42982"

How can I improve it to be fast like the SQL Server one?
My code is in VB, so I'd prefer VB code, but I can translate C# ones to VB so that's cool too :)

===========================================================================
Now, I didn't think that the way the records are added to the datatable plays a role as THAT only takes seconds, but as per @Plutonix request, here's the whole code:

```vb
Private Async Function LoadKinoDrawsFromTextFiles(ByVal FromValue As Integer, ByVal ToValue As Integer, ByVal Files() As String, ByVal dtTable As DataTable) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim Result As DataTable = dtTable.Clone

    Await Task.Run(
        Sub()
            For i As Integer = FromValue To ToValue
                DownloadingDrawsProgress += 1
                Dim FileContent() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Files(i))
                Dim CurLineKinoDrawNum As Integer = -1

                For Each line In FileContent
                    If line <> "" AndAlso line.Length > 10 Then
                        Try
                            Dim LineDecomposition As List(Of String) = line.Split(" "c).ToList

                            Dim NewDataRow As DataRow = Result.NewRow
                            CurLineKinoDrawNum = CInt(LineDecomposition(0))
                            NewDataRow(0) = CurLineKinoDrawNum
                            Try
                                NewDataRow(1) = Date.ParseExact(LineDecomposition(1) & " " & LineDecomposition(2), KinoDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Try
                                    NewDataRow(1) = Date.ParseExact(LineDecomposition(1) & " " & LineDecomposition(2), "d/M/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                Catch exc As Exception
                                    NewDataRow(1) = Date.Parse(LineDecomposition(1) & " " & LineDecomposition(2))
                                End Try
                            End Try
                            NewDataRow(2) = ArrayBox(False, " ", 0UI, False, LineDecomposition.Skip(3), True, "")
                            Result.Rows.Add(NewDataRow)

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Try
                                Dim Tries As Integer = 0
                                Dim DownloadClient As New WebClient With {.Proxy = Nothing}
                                Dim OnlineDrawJSONString As String
                                Dim OnlineDrawJSON As JObject = Nothing

                                Do Until Tries >= 10
                                    Try
                                        OnlineDrawJSONString = DownloadClient.DownloadString(DrawByNumberLink.Replace("{NumIdentifier}", CurLineKinoDrawNum.ToString))
                                        OnlineDrawJSON = JObject.Parse(OnlineDrawJSONString)
                                        Tries = 10
                                    Catch exb As Exception
                                        Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                        Tries += 1
                                    End Try
                                Loop
                                Tries = 0

                                If OnlineDrawJSON Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Unable to download the Draw!")

                                Dim OnlineDrawNum As Integer = OnlineDrawJSON(DrawIdentifier)(DrawNumberIdentifier).Value(Of Integer)()
                                Dim dateStr As String = CStr(OnlineDrawJSON(DrawIdentifier)(DrawDateIdentifier))
                                dateStr = dateStr.Substring(0, dateStr.IndexOf("T")) & " " & dateStr.Substring(dateStr.IndexOf("T") + 1, 5) '5 because it'll always be 5. e.g. "22:00".Length = 5
                                Dim OnlineDrawDate As Date
                                Try
                                    OnlineDrawDate = Date.ParseExact(dateStr, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                Catch exn As Exception
                                    Try
                                        OnlineDrawDate = Date.ParseExact(dateStr, "d-M-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                    Catch exc As Exception
                                        OnlineDrawDate = Date.Parse(dateStr)
                                    End Try
                                End Try

                                Dim OnlineResults As List(Of Integer) = OnlineDrawJSON(DrawIdentifier)(DrawResultsIdentifier).Values(Of Integer)().ToList

                                Dim drRow As DataRow = Result.NewRow
                                drRow(0) = OnlineDrawNum
                                drRow(1) = OnlineDrawDate
                                drRow(2) = ArrayBox(False, " ", 0UI, False, OnlineResults, True, "")
                                Result.Rows.Add(drRow)

                            Catch exc As Exception
                                CreateCrashFile(exc, True,, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                                Exit Sub
                            End Try
                        End Try
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Sub)

    Return Result
End Function

Public Function ArrayBox(Of T)(ByVal doNumeriseItems As Boolean, ByVal DelimitationStr As String, ByVal SplitOnNum As UInteger, ByVal IgnoreNullValues As Boolean, ByVal IETVar As IEnumerable(Of T), Optional ByVal IgnoreDelimitSpace As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal DefaultSpace As String = " ", Optional ByVal AlwaysDelimitBeforeNewLine As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal PrefixString As String = "", Optional ByVal SuffixString As String = "", Optional DoNotPrefixIfValueIsNumeric As Boolean = False, Optional DoNotSuffixIfValueIsNumeric As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal AddTwoDoubleQuotesBeforeADoubleQuoteCharacter As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal StrInCaseOfNullValue As String = " ") As String
    Dim sbRet As New StringBuilder

    If IETVar IsNot Nothing Then
        For i = 0 To IETVar.Count - 1
            If (IETVar(i) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(IETVar(i))) OrElse Not IgnoreNullValues Then   '   If the IEVariable is something
                Dim StringToBeAppended As String = StrInCaseOfNullValue
                Try
                    StringToBeAppended = IETVar(i).ToString
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try

                If doNumeriseItems Then sbRet.Append(i + 1).Append(") ") '      Numerise it if user asked it

                If PrefixString <> "" AndAlso (Not IsNumeric(StringToBeAppended) OrElse Not DoNotPrefixIfValueIsNumeric) Then ' If there is a Prefix set, and value isnt numeric OR, is numeric but prefixing is allowed
                    sbRet.Append(PrefixString) '                                                                                then append it before the actual value
                End If

                If Not AddTwoDoubleQuotesBeforeADoubleQuoteCharacter Then '         If we are to proceed normally,
                    sbRet.Append(StringToBeAppended) '                              Print the Value of IETVar(i)
                Else
                    sbRet.Append(StringToBeAppended.Replace("""", """""""")) '      Else, add 2 double-quotes before any double-quote character
                End If

                If SuffixString <> "" AndAlso (Not IsNumeric(StringToBeAppended) OrElse Not DoNotSuffixIfValueIsNumeric) Then 'If there is a Suffix set, and value isnt numeric OR, is numeric but suffixing is allowed
                    sbRet.Append(SuffixString) '                                                                                    then append it after the actual value
                End If

                If AlwaysDelimitBeforeNewLine AndAlso DelimitationStr <> "" AndAlso i <> IETVar.Count - 1 Then '       If Always Delimit And it isn't the last element of all
                    sbRet.Append(DelimitationStr) '                                                                 then Delimit it
                    If Not IgnoreDelimitSpace AndAlso (SplitOnNum = 0 OrElse (i + 1) Mod SplitOnNum <> 0) Then sbRet.Append(DefaultSpace) ' Put a space if a space should be put

                ElseIf DelimitationStr <> "" AndAlso (SplitOnNum = 0 OrElse (i + 1) Mod SplitOnNum <> 0) AndAlso i <> IETVar.Count - 1 Then '  if it should be delimited And it isn't the last element of the line
                    sbRet.Append(DelimitationStr) '                                                                                         then Delimit it
                    If Not IgnoreDelimitSpace Then sbRet.Append(DefaultSpace) '                                                             Put a space if a space should be put
                End If

                If SplitOnNum <> 0 AndAlso (i + 1) Mod SplitOnNum = 0 AndAlso i <> IETVar.Count - 1 Then '  If you separate them with NewLines and it is the last element of the line
                    sbRet.AppendLine() '                                                                then append a NewLine
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End If

    Return sbRet.ToString
End Function

Public Async Sub FillDatabaseWithDefaultDraws()
Dim SQLiteAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim dtKinoDraws As New DataTable
Dim SQLitecmdBuilder As SQLiteCommandBuilder

'Emptying the Database
ExecuteSQLQuery(<SQL>
                    DELETE FROM [<%= KinoDrawsTableName %>];
                    VACUUM;
                </SQL>.Value)

'This is so we have the SCHEMA to use dtKinoDraws.NewRow later to add the 400.000 rows
SQLiteAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(<SQL>
                                          Select * FROM <%= KinoDrawsTableName %>
                                      </SQL>.Value, SQLConnLite)
SQLitecmdBuilder = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(SQLiteAdapter)

SQLiteAdapter.Fill(dtKinoDraws)
Dim Files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(strKinoDrawsDirPath)

Dim item = Await LoadKinoDrawsFromTextFiles(0, Files.Length - 1, Files, dtKinoDraws)
dtKinoDraws.Merge(item)

SQLiteAdapter.Update(dtKinoDraws)
SQLiteAdapter.Dispose()
SQLConnLite.Close()
End Sub
```

And here's what each file in Files(i) looks like:

> 304454    30/11/2011  21:00   7   65  31  62  21  50  34  70  37  40  16  59  10  41  42  76  78  71  74  47
>
> 304453    30/11/2011  20:55   62  30  68  63  9   45  10  50  1   78  22  6   61  52  38  2   55  26  49  72
>
> 304452    30/11/2011  20:50   45  65  42  1   78  14  16  4   43  70  28  19  67  23  77  40  49  71  22  21
>
> ...
>
> 300971    1/11/2011   10:00   52  48  1   76  13  38  24  18  16  20  53  59  4   40  65  68  42  9   2   51

Comment: SQLite can add insert many 10s of thousands of rows per second (I forget the actual count).  A quick test of INSERTing 750k rows of 5 integers took just  34 secs.  For the code shown, there is a bit more going on than just inserting rows - what does `[Adding the 600.000+ rows to the datatable dtKinoDraws by some way]` do and how?

Comment: The WAY the datatable gets record matter? I wasn't aware of that as the time this gets is not a problem - that only takes seconds. Okay, so dtKinoDraws whose schema was taken off the SQLite table, has 3 columns, 1st an int, 2nd a datetime and 3rd a varchar(255), all NO NULL, 1st is PrimaryKey and there are no indexes. The way it gets the records is too big to describe here, so I'll update my original post

Comment: There is A LOT going on there and some very dubious implementations which can all be done with much less code.  But just add a transaction block and you'll probably be happy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'add a transaction block'. could you please elaborate? I'm also open to suggestions on how to do this with much less code (unless you're talking about ArrayBox(of T)() - then that's okay, it's a general implementation I wrote to use on a plethora of stuff).